# Implementing tags in database schema

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I'm implementing a tag scheme in an existing application. For the sake of simplicity, we can assume that the following table structure is used

```
table comments
-id
-name

table tags
id
name

table comment_tag
comment_id
tag_id
```

So, when a comment is saved (it could be create or update), we get a bunch of tags that need to be created, inserted or deleted from the post_tag table. In fact, there are 3 possible scenarios:

- comment_tag already exists; no action needed
- comment_tag does not yet exist; insert in comment_tag table
- comment_tag removed; delete from comment_tag table

What's the best / most optimal way of doing this?

Option 1: Loop through each of the POSTed tags and taking one of the above 3 routes, depending on the comment_tag status.

Option 2 Delete all records from comment_tag where comment_id = '123', and then doing an insert?

None of these seem really optimal. I'm hoping there is a better option.

Comment: Well that are only two Options. Implement both and then tell us your experience (I could also say: grab yourself a tea and one hour of fresh air with the computer shut down). you  will likely then have the real solution, too.

Answer (score 3):

This should perform optimally, and shows how additional fields can be inserted ***or*** updated:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO comments (name,created) VALUES ('comment', NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updates = updates + 1;

INSERT INTO tags (name,created) VALUES
('tag1', NOW()),
('tag2', NOW()),
('tag3', NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updates = updates + 1;

DELETE
comment_tag
FROM
comment_tag
INNER JOIN
comments c ON c.id = comment_tag.comment_id
LEFT JOIN
tags t ON t.id = comment_tag.tag_id
WHERE
c.name = 'comment' AND
t.name NOT IN ('tag1','tag2','tag3');

INSERT INTO comment_tag (comment_id, tag_id ,created) 
SELECT
c.id AS comment_id,
t.id AS tag_id,
NOW() AS created
FROM
comments c,
tags t
WHERE
c.name = 'comment' AND
t.name IN ('tag1','tag2','tag3')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE comment_tag.updates = comment_tag.updates + 1;

COMMIT;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81f58/1 for an interactive example.

Comment: So, basically Option 2. Delete all the tags for that comment, and then do a fresh insert?

Comment: Actually, I updated the answer to only delete if the tag was removed.